# Pig - Chararray data type and Int data types are converted to Chararray implicitly by Pig when REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL

Tags: arrays, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a sample web log data which has IP, date in `dd/mmm/yyyy` format, url and other details that are generated in a web log. I am trying to separate the web log into fields - IP, date and url. Below are the scripts that I have created in PIG:

```
A = Load 'weblogs_rebuild sample.txt' using TextLoader() as Log:chararray;
B = foreach A generate flatten (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(Log, '([\\S]+)[\\s+-]+[\\[]+([\\d]+)[/]+([\\w]+)[/]+([\\d]+)(.*)[\\]]+[\\s+]+[\\"]+([\\w\\s+/\\d.]+)[\\"]+[\\s+]+(.*)')) as (field1:chararray,date:int,month:chararray,year:int,timefield:chararray,useraction:chararray,userfiled:chararray);
```

when I press enter after creating relation B, it gives me warning

> org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning
>   NO_LOAD_FUNCTION_FOR_CASTING_BYTEARRAY 14 time(s)

If I press run the relation B script again and press enter, the warning message shows

> org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning
>   NO_LOAD_FUNCTION_FOR_CASTING_BYTEARRAY 21 time(s)

When I do describe B, it shows me all fields in bytearray.

```
B: {field1: bytearray,date: bytearray,month: bytearray,year: bytearray,timefield: bytearray,useraction: bytearray,userfiled: bytearray}
```

I am not getting why the numbers are getting multplied by 7 each times and why the datatypes chararray, int have converted to Bytearray.

This is what I see when I do dump B;

```
(364.635.03.677,26,Oct,2011,:22:39:30 -0500,GET /feeds/press HTTP/1.1,200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)")
```

Sample web log:

```
323.81.303.680 - - [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] "GET /download/download6.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19"
668.667.44.3 - - [25/Oct/2011:07:38:30 -0500] "GET /download/download3.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070719 CentOS/1.5.0.12-3.el5.centos Firefox/1.5.0.12"
13.386.648.380 - - [25/Oct/2011:17:06:00 -0500] "GET /download/download6.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; InfoPath.2)"
06.670.03.40 - - [26/Oct/2011:13:24:00 -0500] "GET /product/demos/product2 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
18.656.618.46 - - [26/Oct/2011:17:15:30 -0500] "GET /download/download4.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.22.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Safari/531.22.7"
14.688.663.667 - - [26/Oct/2011:21:02:30 -0500] "GET /news HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
13.07.338.684 - - [26/Oct/2011:21:02:30 -0500] "GET /download HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)"
14.688.663.667 - - [26/Oct/2011:21:02:30 -0500] "GET /news HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "/news" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
```